# Mono hard float latest release is failing for Text box control

Tags: mono

I have installed mono for hard float 3.2.7. If I put Text box control within the C# the code is crashing. Why is text box control is failing in the 3.2.7 (hardfloat) version? Is there a fixed version of mono?

Comment: What is the exception message? Stack trace? Any thing?

Comment: This is the stack trace I get when trying to show a TextBox in mono 3.2.8 hard-float on arm: https://gist.github.com/wiseman/b907de52e8aae0482050

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the version of mono in raspbian (currently all releases), it is belived to be related to an incomplete implementation of the arm hard float ABI. It appears to have been fixed in more recent versions of mono upstream.

There is a repo I put together with more recent mono packages. I believe they fix the issue with the windows forms textbox but there are some compatibility issues with other software. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=99595&p=798116&hilit=mono4#p798076